Jinja2: macro is not called inside template
In an index.html, just before a for loop that calls for a couple of blog posts, I have a defined a macro to use in those posts:
<div class="content">

  {% macro image(source, caption) %}
    <a href="{{ source }}">
      <img src="{{ source }}" alt="{{ caption }}">
    </a>
    <p class="caption">{{ caption }}</p>
  {% endmacro %}
  
  {% block content %}

      {% for post in content['posts'][-5:] %}
          <article>
          <a class="heading" href="{{ post['link'] }}">
              <h2>{{ post['title'] }}</h2>
          </a>
          <p class="date">{{ post['date'] | prettydate }}</p>
          {{ post['body']}}
          <hr class="post">
      {% endfor %}
  {% endblock content %}

The posts are template files with HTML code. In there, I call this macro like this:
{{ image('/content/img/image.jpg', 'My Picture') }}

I had expected this to be rendered using the macro, but it is not. Instead of the picture with the caption, the expression above is rendered as-is.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

The reason the above doesn't work, is because post['body'] is never passed through Jinja's renderer itself. To accomplish that, I could call the rendered myself:
macro = """
    {% macro image(source, caption) %}
        <a href="{{ source }}">
            <img src="{{ source }}" alt="{{ caption }}">
        </a>
        <p class="caption">{{ caption }}</p>
    {% endmacro %}
"""

template = Template(macro+post['body'])
post['body'] = template.render()

